# How do you manually start SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

During installation, I opted for manual startup of my SQL Server 2014 instance. The official MS documentation states that you should enter the following command into a command prompt to start it:

```
sqlservr
```

I tried that, as well as

```
sqlservr.exe
```

However, the command is not recognized, and running the command prompt in administrator mode doesn't work either. How do I manually start SQL Server 2014?

Comment: You need to start the `MSSQLSERVER` Windows service - not the EXE separately....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should use `net start MSSQLSERVER` command to run service, and not executable file you've mentioned.

In most cases, the `sqlservr.exe` program is only used for troubleshooting or major maintenance.

Also it makes sense where exactly this executable is located. 
For the default instance, run sqlservr from the \MSSQL\Binn directory. For a named instance, run sqlservr from the \MSSQL$instance_name\Binn directory.

When SQL Server is started from the command prompt with `sqlservr.exe`, SQL Server **does not start as a service**, so you cannot stop SQL Server using net commands.

See [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx) about starting and stopping SQL Server and [sqlservr.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162819.aspx) related article.